Создание манифеста к миниатюрам, через ffmpeg
Создание миниатюр
ffmpeg -i {file} -map_metadata -1 -c:v libwebp -fps_mode vfr 
-vf "select=\'isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,10)\',scale=-1:200,tile=5x5"
/c_thumb%01d.webp

Предположим на одном изображении 10 миниатюр.
При попытке создать минифест, самый простой
ffmpeg -i {file} -map 0 -f dash -seg_duration 4 \
-thumbnails "1" \
-init_seg_name "init.mp4" \
-media_seg_name "chunk_$Number$.m4s" \
-output /output.mpd

Unrecognized option 'thumbnails'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Как создать манифест под миниатюры в целом.
И как создать манифест под следующие параметры

Продолжительность видео 150 секунд. На выходе 2 изображения(интерфал между миниатюрами 10 секунд, а количество миниатюр на одном изображении 10). Одно изображение на 100 сек...
Высота миниатюры 200, а ширина адаптивная...

Каким образом сгенерировать манифест под миниатюры с указанными выше интервалами и адаптивной шириной под высоту миниатюры?
